# Limit one submission from each user using Contact Form 7?

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

I am using [Contact Form 7](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/) along with the add-on [Contact Form 7 Dynamic Text Extension](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension/) to pre-populate usernames and emails.

I know this may be sort of a strange request but I want to be able to limit the number of submissions to one for each user only for one of my forms. Basically, it's a submission form for a contest and I don't want users to be able to submit over and over again.

Is something like this possible with this plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contact Form 7 does not save form submissions to a database, so you have no saved previous form submissions to check a current submission against.

That means you'll need to have a plugin that can save entries to a database (the plugin author seems to recommend "Flamingo" for that). Once you've got those, you'll need to figure out how to check each submission against the database unless that function's built-in to the new plugin you install.

Some plugins like Gravity Forms (paid, but I highly recommend it) include this functionality built in.

Comment: I know Gravity Forms has an option to limit the number of entries but looking at the options (http://i.imgur.com/McXVb.jpg), it's confusing as to whether it means total number of all users or total number per user. I would like the latter. Do you know by any chance?

Comment: I believe that you put the restriction on the email or user field (or both). Use whichever you want to restrict the form submissions by.